# string array is not assigned properly to each color

Tags: bash

Recently,i came up with a good idea to make a rainbow text but it keeps failing.I tried to make a nest loop so each color and string in their array can be assigned together to make a cool looking text.

```
output=(Z y r o V P N)
rainbow=(9 202 11 46 43 90 91)
for i in ${rainbow[*]}
do
    for x in ${output[*]}
    do
        echo -e "\e[38;5;${i}m${x}\e[0m"
    done
done
```

but this what occur
[all text is colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG5LS.png)

hope it can be solved

Comment: Did you mean to color each letter in 'output' something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over both loops **together**:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   output=(Z y r o V P N)
   rainbow=(9 202 11 46 43 90 91)
   for i in $(seq 0 ${#output[*]}); do
       echo -en "\e[38;5;${rainbow[i]}m${output[i]}\e[0m"
   done
   echo
```

The `-n` prevents a new line and the final echo adds it.

Comment: btw what is the use of seq?

Comment: It generates a list of all numbers between 0 and the output length. Also please, accept if this is what you meant/need.

Comment: In `bash`, it's more efficient to iterate over `${!output[@]}` instead. No need to use an external command `seq` that isn't guaranteed to exist on your underlying platform.